# I want Automatically Reload facebook page code in this imacro facebook unlike code

Tags: imacros

I want Automatically Reload facebook page when 30 facebook fan page automatically unlike then is page autamically reload and again unlike start which code include in this pagebook page unlike imacro code and where?this code show in beleow.

```
var unlike,rnlike;
unlike =  "CODE:";
unlike += "VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
//unlike += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
unlike += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
unlike += "'URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/browse/other_connections_of/" + "\n";
unlike += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:uiButtonText&&TXT:Unlike" + "\n";
unlike += "wait seconds=2" + "\n";
var n=prompt("Please enter number of unlikes:");
var start;
start = iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/browse/other_connections_of/");

main:
{
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
    iimSet("j", j)
    rnlike=iimPlay(unlike);
    if (rnlike == -101) // abort script if user presses Stop button
            {
            break main;
            }
    if (rnlike == -802)//refresh if timeout
            {   
            iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH",30);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    main:
    {
    var count=0;
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
    if(count==30){
    iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH",30);
    count=0;
    j=0;
    continue;
    }     
    count++;
        iimSet("j", j)
        rnlike=iimPlay(unlike);
        if (rnlike == -101) // abort script if user presses Stop button
                {
                break main;
                }
        if (rnlike == -802)//refresh if timeout
                {   
                iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH",30);
                }
}}
```

Comment: not working show this error. SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement, line: NaN (Error code: 991)

Comment: well, you can add by yourself missing } don't just copy-paste it like robot

Comment: i don't know where missing this } code. whose code i give you that code working well so problem your code whose you give me. i think here is some missing. i don't understand. what and where missing. can you tell me?

Comment: added } at the end, and your code also missing it since I copied your code stated above.